How to access trimmed commit SHA using GitHub Actions in run_name of workflow?
What do I actually need?
I need to print as a job title the number/hash/id of referenced commit. Is it possible?
Using the screenshot, I mean:

The following tries didn't work:
 name: My App Development
 run-name: //here one of the below

 ${{ github.event.head_commit.tree_id }}
 ${{ github.event.head_commit.id }}
 ${{ github.event.push.head_commit.id }}


See github.sha.

Ok, I tried and... the result is 223ba8df1dbb3c28d3efca8d870596e6eb72c330, but in source tree there is displayed only 223ba8df1? Is it kind of shorten sha? Is it just trimmed or what?;)

Is there a way to print a trimmed sha here?

You'll have to do that in a separate step. Depending on the shell, you can extract the part you need and set it as an env var or an output param for subsequent use.

what about this: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-sha-trimmer. Can I just use it like:
uses: priyesh2609/sha-trim-action@v1.1.2, ${{ github.trimmed_sha }}?

Currently, the short form is not available in github context so you cannot use it in run-name.

The github context only includes the full commit sha, i.e., ${{github.sha }}, so you have to calculate the short sha yourself and make it available to subsequent steps/jobs. You can extract the short sha with ${{ github.sha::0:7 }} on Linux and '${{ github.sha }}'.Substring(0, 7) on Windows.

Example usage in the different steps:

steps:
  - name: Calculate short SHA
    run: echo "short_sha=${{ github.sha::0:7 }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    id: calc_sha

  - name: Use short SHA
    run: echo "Short SHA: ${{ steps.calc_sha.outputs.short_sha }}"


Example usage in the different jobs:

jobs:
  calculate_sha:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      short_sha: ${{ steps.calc_sha.outputs.short_sha }}
    steps:
      - name: Calculate short SHA
        run: echo "short_sha=${{ github.sha::0:7 }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        id: calc_sha

  use_short_sha:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: calculate_sha
    steps:
      - name: Use short SHA
        run: echo "Short SHA: ${{ needs.calculate_sha.outputs.short_sha }}"


Ok, I need to use it in run_name. How can I do it there? Not in jobs, and not in steps.

Have you tried putting it in the runname, for example: run-name: {{ github.sha::0:7 }}?

I will try it later and let you know;)

@Bademeister Unexpected symbol: 'sha::0:7'. Located at position 8 within expression: github.sha::0:7

I don’t think there is a built in way to trim strings or extract substrings (https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26625) so you might not be able to use it directly in the run-name. An alternative might be using a reusable workflow then passing the short SHA as an input.
